# How do I format decimals in C?

Tags: c

This is my print statement:

```
printf("%d     %f\n",kPower, raisePower);
```

This is my output:

```
-4     0.000100
-3     0.001000
-2     0.010000
-1     0.100000
0     1.000000
1     10.000000
2     100.000000
3     1000.000000
4     10000.000000
```

I want it to be printed like this:

[image]

**UPDATE**

So I made my positive values line up:

```
-4            0.0
-3            0.0
-2            0.0
-1            0.1
0            1.0
1           10.0
2          100.0
3         1000.0
4        10000.0
```

This is my new code so far:

```
printf("%d     %10.1f\n",kPower, raisePower);
```

I don't know, should I make a for loop to print each one (positive results vs negative result) in a different format?

Comment: Now *that* is what I call a spec! Are you looking for a project manager position?

Comment: How come this gets upvotes. The answer is one websearch away.

Comment: @rr- I'm confused on how to format everything, I'm new to C :)

Comment: Did you *carefully* read the documentation of [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf). The answer is inside it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch sure let me see!

Comment: @rr- They must be fans of Frozen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calculating the powers first using `pow()` from `math.h` and then:

You can use %10f to precede the number with blanks in the example total of 10 spaces:

```
printf ("Preceding with blanks: %10f \n", 10000.01);
```

Source: [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Comment: But for the floating point part, OP needs `%f` or something related.

Comment: Basically, `%10.5f`, but to only print the decimals if they are needed. I don't think thats something `printf()` can do directly, I'd be surprised if there was a way.

Comment: @Havenard what does the 10 format and what does the .5 format in %10.5f?

Comment: @Elsa It means your floating pointer should be printed in a space of 10 digits (total including the dot and decimals), and padded with blank spaces to the left if necessary, and it should be printed with 5 decimal digits of precision. You can make it pad with zeros with `%010.5f`. You can make it pad with spaces to the right with `%-10.5f`.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *get_number_formatted(double f)
{
    static char buf[128]; // this function is not thread-safe
    int i, j;

    i = snprintf(buf, 128, "%20.10f", f) - 2;

    for (j = i - 8; i > j; --i)
        if (buf[i] != '0')
            break;

    buf[i + 1] = '\0';
    return buf;
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    for (i = -4; i < 5; ++i)
        printf("%5d %s\n", i, get_number_formatted(pow(10.0, i)));
   return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/KBiSu0

Output:

```
   -4         0.0001
   -3         0.001
   -2         0.01
   -1         0.1
    0         1.0
    1        10.0
    2       100.0
    3      1000.0
    4     10000.0
```

`printf()` cannot print a variating length of decimal digits, so basically what I did was print the formatted number into a buffer and then cut the exceeding zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Basicly you can use variable length to perform this:

```
printf("%d %.*lf", kPower, -kPower, raisePower);
```

---

Advantage over other methods is that this method does not need any extra buffer(s)

Answer (score 2):

With a little help of `modf`, you can use `%g` to skip the trailing zeroes and `\b` to skip the leading zero:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, iarr[] = {-4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
    double darr[] = {0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1., 10., 100., 1000., 10000.};
    double intpart, fractpart;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        fractpart = modf(darr[i], &intpart);
        if (fractpart == 0.0)
            printf("%10d%10d.0\n", iarr[i], (int)intpart);
        else
            printf("%10d%10d\b%g\n", iarr[i], (int)intpart, fractpart);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    -4         0.0001
    -3         0.001
    -2         0.01
    -1         0.1
     0         1.0
     1        10.0
     2       100.0
     3      1000.0
     4     10000.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this example code

```
float y[7]={0.000100f,0.0010f,0.0100,0.1000f,1.0f,10.000f,100.00f};
int a[7]={-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2};
for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    printf("%2d%20f\n",a[i],y[i]);
```

Output will like that.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but that's not what was required.

Comment: @glglgl, yaa i know the problem is with trailing `0`'s .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sprintf` and then trim the zeros. This is the same idea as @Havenard's answer, but writing spaces over the zeros instead of cutting the string.
And my C-style is somewhat different FWIW. My style is that I don't want to count or do any arithmetic in my head; that's what the C optimizer is for :).

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int kPower;
    for(kPower=-4; kPower<5; kPower++){
        enum { bufsize = 2+5+10+1+4+1+1 };
        char buf[bufsize];
        int j,n,i;
        double raisePower = pow(10,kPower);
        //printf("%2d     %10.4f\n",kPower,raisePower);
        snprintf(buf,bufsize,"%2d     %10.4f\n",kPower,raisePower);
        j=strchr(buf,'.')-buf;
        j+=1;
        n=strchr(buf+j,'\n')-buf;
        for (i=n-1; i>j; i--)
            if (buf[i]=='0')
                buf[i]=' ';
            else
                break;
        printf("%s",buf);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
-4         0.0001
-3         0.001 
-2         0.01  
-1         0.1   
 0         1.0   
 1        10.0   
 2       100.0   
 3      1000.0   
 4     10000.0
```

Answer (score 0):

use printf like this:

```
printf( "%5d %10.1f\n",kPower, raisePower);

this will result in kPower being printed, 
    right justified, 
    in 5 columns
    - sign in the right place

this will result in raisePower being printed with:
    10 columns
    leading 0s replaced by spaces
        except 1 digit (could be 0) to the left of the decimal point
    1 (rounded) digit to the right of the decimal point
    - signs being printed at the proper location
    decimal point being aligned
```